# Network connectivity issues on apps and sites with SSL

Tags: internet, https

I'm using Asus Memo Pad (ME172V) running Android 4.1.1. Apps (Facebook, Play Store, Yahoo! Mail, Skype, etc) cannot access the WiFi network. I can browse using Chrome (except for SSL sites) and can use the YouTube app.

Tried:

- Rebooting via safe mode
- Clear app cache
- Removing and adding accounts

Answer (score 1):

<sup>As the OP didn't add the solution as an answer himself...</sup>

OP found the answer to the issue himself, strange as it might sound:

> noticed that the device date and time is not correct. corrected it and it worked.

On a second thought, this is a very plausible reason, considering the questions hint about *except for SSL sites*: If the local date is too far in the past, SSL certificates are "not yet valid" -- and if it's too far in the future, they are "no longer valid". In both cases, establishing a secured connection must fail.